# Use Python to calculate monthly average of runoff data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I want to calculate the monthly mean of certain runoff data, so far I've tried this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('runoff_data.xlsx', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
df['Year'] = df.index.year
df['Month'] = df.index.month
n = df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df['Year'], freq='M'))['Flow_1', 'Flow_2'].mean()
```

And it only comes in year but not in month
and when i tried to type in Month, the 'freq' is not correct
i want each month's average.
Can somebody help me, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use month periods generated from `DatetimeIndex` for avoid lost information about `months`:

```
n = df.groupby(df.index.to_period('m'))[['Flow_1', 'Flow_2']].mean()
```

Or:

```
n = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='m'))[['Flow_1', 'Flow_2']].mean()
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
n = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month'])[['Flow_1', 'Flow_2']].mean()
```

Comment: hey thanks, that really works